# Auto import always suggests incorrect file type (tsx -> js), how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

When I import a React component in vscode, vscode suggests me to import the file `xxx/index.js`, but the source file has a `.tsx` extension.

I've tried to set `allowJs: true` in `tsconfig.json`, but it does not work.

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "outDir": "./public",
    "module": "esNext",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "esnext",
    ],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules",
    "./public"
  ]
}
```

webpack config

```
resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx", ".json"]
  },
```

For example, when I import the file `a/b/c/index.tsx`, vscode should suggest me one of the following instead of `a/b/c/index.js`:

1. `a/b/c/index.tsx`
2. `a/b/c`.

Comment: if you use VSCode, try this extension ```nucllear.vscode-extension-auto-import```

Comment: I installed this extension, It seemed no difference @its4zahoor

Comment: I started seeing this as well. Unfortunately, it doesn't happen with every file. Some times, it will show the correct import. I went through the code and don't see an obvious difference between the two.

Comment: The issue for me was due to a different import. In the files that this was happening, I also had an "import * as" import statement...
```
import * as lists from '../assets/lang/en_us/lists.json';
```
I'm not sure if it's the import * or the fact that I'm importing a .json, but I commented out that import on several file and tested and the default import showed up properly.
As far as a fix...I looked through the settings (VSC for mac) and couldn't find anything that would help.  I'm guessing it was an update that broke it, so we'll probably have to deal with it.